Not able to switch the browser based on tags in specflow
I am executing the Specflow BDD test and due to some issue on Chrome I need to do some tests on Firefox and rest of the tests on Chrome.
Setup I did:
Add @Firefox Tag to the scenario which needs to be executed on Firefox
[BeforeScenario]
string[] tags = scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Tags
if (tags.Contains("firefox")) {
    Executions.Browser = "firefox";
} else {
    Execution.Browser = "chrome";
}

Additional Setup:
Executions is getting the value from appsettings. Browser is a static property in this class.
At [BeforeTest] I am loading all my appsettings properties and deserializing them to Executions class (here Browser is also set to Chrome).
Execution.Browser is further being used to initialize the required driver.
So

BeforeTest code is setting Browser to 'Chrome'.
In BeforeScenario I want to again set the value as mentioned again.

Problem: When running the tests in parallel, the tests not having the Firefox tags are also executed on Firefox, which I don't want.
How can I sort this out?

some issue on Chrome what issue? Are you sure its' not a bug in your test? If the test can't work with Chrome, you have a test failure. Most end users use a Chromium-based browser. The whole point of web testing is to ensure the tests pass for all browsers

no , Some of the older js in the application are not loading on chrome 123 which in turn are not executing the required method to perform operations.

Besides, there's no Selenium-related code in the question. Specflow isn't a web testing framework and setting Executions.Browser won't call new FirefoxDriver or new ChromeDriver.

Some of the older js in the application are not loading so you do have a test failure that needs fixing. Chrome didn't just decide to break some JS functionality. If you don't fix the error, your web app will fail on all clients in a matter of weeks, as Chrome installations automatically update themselves

Executions.Browser is further being used to invoke required browser. I am looking for some help how to change the value for Execution.Browser based on tags so that required driver can be inoked

Issue is being investigated however this is added as a temp solution to see if we can execute this run for a priority run tonight

The code does matter, because as I read the Specflow docs I see that the tag should be a parameter to the BeforeScenario attribute. The code you posted seems to modify a global variable so yes, if you execute multiple steps in parallel you end up with a race condition, as one test ends up reading a Browser set by a different one.

You have a mix of Execution and Executions in your code and description. I'm assuming that one is a typo... you should fix that throughout your question to make it clearer.

You likely shouldn't be setting the browser twice... in BeforeTest and BeforeScenario. If you are trying to allow different browsers for each test, then it seems like it should be in BeforeTest but I don't use specflow. You should probably read the docs and figure out where it's supposed to be set. If you set it too high, more than one test may end up getting the wrong browser values.

What is Execution or Executions? I don't see that anywhere in the SpecFlow docs. Is that an injected class? To share state between scenario steps in the same thread you need to store it in ScenarioContext. I suspect the Execution object is shared among all steps, so changing the browser in one thread changes it for all others.

The C# in your post is not valid. Please [edit] your question to include a [repro] which is also valid C#.

We also need to see the code that initializes the web driver.
